# Search inside sharepoint designer

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I'm using SharePoint designer and trying to find the "search in files option" throw all SharePoint project, something like in visual studio "search and replace".
Is such simple option available in visual designer 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That option is not available in Sharepoint Designer.

Search in files option searches on files in your file system.

Sharepoint designer runs on your computer but it extracts data from the server using web services no files are actually on your computer so that feature is obviously not implemented.

It could be implemented on the server side and provided as a service. But bear in mind that data is also not stored on the file system in sharepoint but in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Luis answer is not correct, at least not for Sharepoint Designer 2013. Click on "Site Pages", choose any page, press control + f to bring up find. Sharepoint Designer 2013 will pull down all the files associated with your site and begin searching them. You will need appropriate permissions.

Comment: In SPD 2010, it doesn't do anything. What I want to do is search within all the *.css files for specific text, but...I don't see how to do it.

Comment: B. Clay, see my reply. I know, old post, but if I found this question, someone else will, too.

Answer (score 1):

The "All Pages" option will search your entire SharePoint site. I don't recommend it, it can be quite time-consuming and give you a lot of false positives.

Unfortunately, the only way to search multiple files is brute force:

- Close all open tabs.
- In the Navigation Pane, open the folder you want to search (such as "Site Assets").
- Right-click each file you want to search, and click "Edit in Advanced Mode".
- Repeat for each folder.
- Open the Find dialog.
- Click "Open page(s)" under "Find where:"
- Your search will include all open tabs.